# SSIS data validation checks for data transfer

Tags: sql, ssis

Data transfer from Excel to SQL table.
Before transfer i need to validate the data(basic data validation).

1. Want to check if ColT is not blank or not Null
2. Want to check if ColB is Integers only
3. Want to check if ColG is Alpha only.

I kind of have an idea how to do this, using Staging tables before transferring the data into Final table but **I'm looking for different solution something like using a Script task and try Pop up msg as soon as one of checks fail.**

**Basically iterate data in script task and then do the validation in script.
Shoot an Popup as soon as validation fails.**

Let me know if that's possible.
Thanks,
Cindy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things if you don't wanna go in script task.

1.get everything in database and then perform what ever check you want to do.

2.Else go for condition Split and check these condition and then only insert the record.

Need any more help Shout. :)

Comment: How to check, if column values are combination of Integers and decimals, such as 100 0.0234 90 9.451. **I tried to use Type casts Real and Decimal but not sure how to format the expression, dont know the syntax**

Comment: u mean you have multiple type of values in same column ? these values are separated by some delimiter ?

Comment: Forget about that, tell me how to build expression/condition to check for integers only.

Answer (score 0):

Between the source and destitution from data transformation task choose data conversion task. Link to this source and destination. Right click on data conversion task and click on edit. Here you can check every. Like some field has null value or not etc.( Red link means when error will occurs then do some other task.)

Comment: Can you provide an basic example for something like data exists or not in this field.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the complete answer but got a start.