# SSIS for testing bulk data

Tags: testing, ssis

can SSIS be used in testing excel files containing large volumes of data (around 50,000 rows) and that needs to be verified against the data available in database. The format and content of the data needs to be validated.

I am new to SSIS and I have been trying implementing SSIS for some time now and I am not sure if i am investing my time in correct place.
Has anyone done a similar kind of implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ton of information on the web about this.

You can accomplish this using SQL Import/ Export tool or SSIS. Depends on how complex/simple you want to get.

If you're trying to automate this, then SSIS is a better choice.

The primary use for SSIS is data warehousing as the product features a fast and flexible tool for data ETL and validations.

what all does SSIS do? [Here's a little answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454802/what-is-the-ssis-package-and-what-does-it-do)

[How to perform Validation?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be097758-278e-430c-9be9-9bcbc7da3bad/data-validations-in-ssis)
Another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745026/ssis-data-validation-checks-for-data-transfer)

Hope this helps.